# First hitting time of a symmetric random walk

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

**Definitions:**

Let $\xi_n$ be a symmetric random walk, i.e.,
$$ 
\xi_n=\eta_1+\eta_2+\dots+\eta_n,
$$
where $\{\eta_n\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that
$$
P\{\eta_n=1\}=P\{\eta_n=-1\}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Furthermore, we define the first hitting time to be $$\tau=\min\left\{n:|\xi_n|=K\right\},$$
where $K$ is a positive integer.

---

I was reading a book on stochastic processes and here we want to show that $\tau<\infty$ a.s. The book proves this as follows

> We want to show that $P\{\tau=\infty\}=0.$ To this end we shall estimate $P\{\tau>2Kn\}.$ Notice that $$P\{\tau>2Kn\}\le \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2K}}\right)^n\longrightarrow 0$$ as $n\to\infty.$ Thus, we have \begin{align}
> P\{\tau=\infty\}&=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty P\{\tau>2Kn\} \\ &=\lim_{n\to\infty} P\{\tau>2Kn\}=0.
> \end{align}

After spending some time, I could not figure out how to get the inequality $$P\{\tau>2Kn\}\le \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2K}}\right)^n$$ in the first line of the proof. Can someone help me understand why this inequality holds?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\frac{1}{2^{2K}}$ is the probability of $2K$ successive $+1$s in a row in an attempt of $2K$ steps. If this happens you must either hit the upper boundary or must have started below the lower boundary, since they are $2K$ apart.
- $1-\frac{1}{2^{2K}}$ is the probability of not having $2K$ successive $+1$s in a row  in an attempt of $2K$ steps.
- $\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2K}}\right)^n$ is the probability of not having $2K$ successive $+1$s in a row in any of $n$ independent attempts of $2K$ steps ($2Kn$ steps in total).
- That last probability is therefore less than or equal to the probability of never hitting the boundary in $2Kn$ steps, which is $P\{\tau>2Kn\}$.

Tighter bounds are possible but unnecessary.